# Уменьшение повторяющегося кода в Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть 3 однотипных фрагмента:

- все от `v4.Fragment` расширяются
- все имеют почти одинаковый `onCreateView()`, в который просто разная информация загружается, но разметка одинаковая

Может можно сделать какой-то свой класс, который расширить `v4.Fragment`, в нем прописать все схожее как-то, а потом расширить свои 3 фрагмента от нового кастомного класса фрагмента ?

Answer (score 2):

Если фрагменты различаются только контентом, то не нужно создавать три разных фрагмента - нужно создать один и менять в нем контент.

Если фрагменты различаются бизнес-логикой, то тогда создаете фрагмент с общими методами, три других наследуете от него и переопределяете методы, в которых логика различается.

Comment: А можно пример ? Чтобы было понятно.

Comment: @web_alex По первому случаю, при вызове фрагмента из активити через `setArguments()` передаете в него контент (указания, какой использовать контент, напр. в случае БД имя таблицы и тп.). В фрагменте получаете эти аргументы и формируете по ним контент. Во втором случае обычное наследование. Для кода недостаточно подробностей в вопросе. Конкретные реализации могут существенно отличаться от источника контента.

Comment: Разметка фрагментов одинаковая: все содержат в себе exandableListView.  В методах onCreateView() я наполняю этот списко по этому примеру - http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/86-urok-45-spisok-derevo-expandablelistview